# Modeling Approach for ID Persistence

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, predictive-modeling, anomaly-detection

I'm modeling a noisy dataset of ID's and have been tasked with creating a model to predict whether an ID exists at some arbitrary point in time. This is necessary, because an ID may not be observed at any particular time step, let's say week. The idea is that if an ID doesn't show up for that week, it may or may not have ceased to exist. You can imagine, if the ID hasn't been seen for more and more consecutive weeks, the likelihood it has ceased to exist goes up.

Are there any pre-established approaches to handling this sort of persistence problem? I've already built a basic model for the problem using exogenous and endogenous variables that works fairly well, but wanted to see if there's any work that's been done on this sort of problem before.

Thanks!

Comment: What determines when something "ceases to exist"? If you have a label for that, in sufficient cases, it sounds like you can apply standard supervised learning.

Comment: @JonNordby So there's no real, ground truth. We just have to rely on an ID not being seen for say, a year, to be considered "ceased to exist". If it hasn't been seen in the data for all of a few days, that ID may have ceased to exist, but given data resolution, this may not be the case. 

You can imagine, we have higher confidence that an ID did not cease to exist if it has spotty appearances, as any single, short disappearance is to be expected.